# writing/reading to/from a dynamic_bitset in a file c++

Tags: c++, string, c++11, vector, boost-dynamic-bitset

So I am converting the bit string to a vector of type int and then pushing the elements of vector in dynamic_bitset object and writing that object into file. Here is my code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/dynamic_bitset.hpp>
#include <fstream>
#include <streambuf>
#include "Utility.h"
using namespace std;
using namespace boost;

class BitOperations {
private:
    string data;
    int size;
    dynamic_bitset<unsigned char> Bits;
    string fName;

public:
    // BitOperations(dynamic_bitset<unsigned char> b){
    //     Bits = b;
    //     size = b.size();
    // }

    // BitOperations(dynamic_bitset<unsigned char> b, string fName){
    //     Bits = b;
    //     this->fName = fName;
    //     size = b.size();
    // }

    BitOperations(string data, string fName){
        this->data = data;
        this->fName = fName;
    }

    void writeToFile(){
        if (data != ""){
            vector<int> bitTemp;
            bitTemp = extractIntegers(data);
            for (int i = 0; i < bitTemp.size(); i++){
                Bits.push_back(bitTemp[i]);
            }
            // for (int i = 0; i < bitTemp.size(); i++){
            //     cout << Bits[i] << " ";
            // }
            // cout << endl;
        }
        ofstream output(fName, ios::binary);
        ostream_iterator<char> osit(output);
        to_block_range(Bits, osit);
    }

    dynamic_bitset<unsigned char> readFromFile(){
        int count = 0;
        ifstream t(fName);
        string str((std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(t)),
                 std::istreambuf_iterator<char>());
        cout << str << endl;
        dynamic_bitset<unsigned char> b;
        int bitLen = str.length() * 8;
        for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++){
            for (int j = 0; j < 8; ++j){
                bool isSet = str[i] & (1 << j);
                b.push_back(isSet);
            }
        }

        return b;
    }
};
```

Here is the code for converting bit string into vector type of integer.

```
vector<int> extractIntegers(string s){
    stringstream stream;
    stream << s;

    string tmp;
    int flag;
    vector<int> nums;

    while (!stream.eof()){
        stream >> tmp;
        if (stringstream(tmp) >> flag){
            nums.push_back(flag);
        }
        tmp = "";
    }
    return nums;
}
```

I tried to print the elements of "Bits" but it does not print anything and also has length of 1.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What do you store in string s?

Comment: I am giving a bit string like "10110100". and getting these into a vector of integer like 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0.

Comment: You want that the vector nums to be like that: {1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0}? Why are you using stringstream, instead of iteration through string?

Comment: If I iterate through string, it will give me the ascii values like {49, 48, 49, 49, 48, 49, 48, 48}.

Comment: Yeah, that's because the chars are stored in ASCII code. Look at my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use `stringstream`.

I iterate through string while s[i] is not the null character('\0'). You could use `std::iterator` instead. Then I push into `nums` vector the number from string, but in the string, '0' char is 48 (ASCII conversion), so I add the `s[i]-'0'`, which is 0 for '0' char and 1 for '1' ( that's works for other number too).

```
vector<int> extractIntegers(string s)
{
    char tmp;
    vector<int> nums;

    for ( int i = 0; s[i]; i++ )
        nums.push_back(s[i] - '0');

    return nums;
}
```